# prawn gem for PDF generation, not enough space if A4 page size is used. Rails 3.2.8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn

I have got an ExportPdf class which inherits a Prawn :: Document like this -

```
class ExportPdf < Prawn::Document

  def initialize(vehicles, view, page, *args)

   super({:top_margin => 70, :page_size => 'A1'}) 
   @view = view
   @page = page


   file_heading
   table_data
 end

 def table_data
  move_down 30

    table table_data_rows do
    row(0).font_style = :bold
    self.row_colors = ["DDDDDD", "FFFFFF"]
    self.header = true
  end

But I have atleast 20 table columns and the only way to accommodate is by increasing page size as,    
     :page_size => 'A1'.
```

But this would make it unprintable, since printing in A4 layout would no longer be possible. How to reduce the font size or something to accommodate all 20 table columns and be able print it in A4 layout ?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use/add `cell_style`

Example:

```
:cell_style => { :size => 10,:border_color => "FFFFFF",:text_color => "333333", :padding => 0, :inline_format => true}
```

Change the size value to change the font size of the table texts.